# Silverlight: Make the listbox background transparent?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a ListBox. It has a white background. How can I get rid of it?

Here is the XAML I'm trying. Whatever I do, I can't get rid of that background. (I'm not sure if it's on each item, which happen to take up all the space in the `ListBox`, or if it's on the background of the `ListBox` itself.)

```
<ListBox x:Name="topThreeHits" ItemsSource="{Binding TopThreeHits}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,0" Background="Transparent">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image, FallbackValue=/PlumPudding;component/Images/file.png}" />
                            <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='File Name'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <Run Text="." Foreground="#787878" FontWeight="Light" />
                            <Run Text="{Binding TypeExtension, FallbackValue='type'}" Foreground="#787878" FontWeight="Light" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add a Border around the ListBox with a Green Background and set the Background to Transparent for your ListBox and it seems to be working fine.

```
<Border Background="Green">
    <ListBox x:Name="topThreeHits"
             Background="Transparent"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,0" Background="Transparent">  
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image, FallbackValue=/PlumPudding;component/Images/file.png}" />  
                    <TextBlock>  
                    <Run Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='File Name'}" FontWeight="Bold" />  
                    <Run Text="." Foreground="#787878" FontWeight="Light" />  
                    <Run Text="{Binding TypeExtension, FallbackValue='type'}" Foreground="#787878" FontWeight="Light" />  
                    </TextBlock>  
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine, and properly setting the background style. I am assuming what you want to do is blow away the default item container completely so there is no background, including rollovers, etc.

**The best way to do that is like this:**

```
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template" >
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Actually, all I wanted to do is remove the background. I wanted to keep the rollover. I added the code you posted to the code I had above, and now the data binding isn't working - it's filled with default fallback values. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted to do without having to retemplate every property of the listboxitem. Much simpler, thanks.